# Sql Server strict convert from varchar to datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime, strict

I'm converting varchar to datetime in Sql Server 2005. Can I force Sql Server to fail if provided varchar has unexpected format?

Example:

```
select convert(datetime, '01-2010-02', 103)
```

Expected result: query fails because 103 means dd/mm/yyyy (see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28SQL.90%29.aspx)).

Actual result: 2010-02-01 00:00:00.000

Main purpose of requested enforcement is order of day and month. If varchar is provided in format yyyy-mm-dd then Sql Server will treat mm as day and dd as month because of day/month order in provided format (dd/mm/yyyy).

**Note**: I can write custom function to manually handle this case. But I hope such enterprise DB already can work strictly with data.

Comment: It would be easier if you could just use the "safe" datetime formats - there are three formats which SQL Server never gets wrong when converting to datetime, and you don't need to supply a format parameter. The one for dates (with no time component) is `yyyymmdd` with no separators.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you have to use [CLR Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179545.aspx) and take advantage of using [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) method. Not an elegant solution but could work.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever SQL Server sees a clear candidate for Year, it will always be used as Year.

The remaining DM parts are determined from the order within the DMY setting or the convert format.  If that weren't true, then very simple conversions will fall apart.

Example

```
set dateformat dmy
select 1 a,CONVERT(datetime, '1-2-3') b
union all
select 2,CONVERT(datetime, '2001-2-3')
union all
select 3,CONVERT(datetime, '2001-3-2')
```

Output

```
a           b
----------- -----------------------
1           2003-02-01 00:00:00.000
2           2001-03-02 00:00:00.000
3           2001-02-03 00:00:00.000
```

The 2nd and 3rd explicitly put the Year in front, and that is **ok**

---

#### EDIT

Books Online has this to say http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx#StringLiteralDateandTimeFormats

There are quite a few exceptions to SET DATEFORMAT, which plays a role regardless of the 3rd param to CONVERT.

- The SET DATEFORMAT session setting does not apply to all-numeric date entries
- This [ISO 8601] format is not affected by the SET DATEFORMAT, SET LANGUAGE, of login default language settings.
- The SET DATEFORMAT session setting is not applied when you specify the month in alphabetical form.
- etc

***To specifically validate dd/mm/yyyy, use the below instead***

```
set dateformat dmy
declare @input varchar(10) set @input = '12-2010-01'

-- convert allows the date through
select convert(datetime, @input, 103) -- 2010-01-12 00:00:00.000

-- the case below returns 0 { = invalid date }
-- this uses 8-digit format which is always interpreted YYYYMMDD regardless
-- of language or dateformat settings
select case
    when @input not like '__/__/____' then 0
    else isdate(right(@input,4)+right(left(@input,5),2)+left(@input,2))
    end
```

Comment: 'Set dateformat dmy' will work for dd/mm/yyyy but in case of yyyy-mm-dd day and month will be silently swapped. That's why I want to force format. I know order of day and month for expected format but I don't know the order for any other format.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the date with a convert to datetime and back again. I don't know for sure if there are any pitfalls doing like this but my limited tests has not discovered any.

```
if @StrDate = convert(varchar(10), convert(datetime, @StrDate, 103) ,103)
```

Comment: I believe there can be, for example if the original string has no leading zeros , like `24/2/2011`.

Comment: @Andriy You are right. But only if no leading zeros is acceptable and I guess that depends on where in the world it is used. Where I come from it is not ok. If both should be allowed you must do some string manipulation, inserting zeros before comparing.

Comment: With such surprises from Sql Server I'd better manually check format of provided string: if(@StrDate like '[0-9][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')

Comment: @Vladimir except that allows dates like 99/99/9999 and even if you restrict days to 31, you can get 31/02/2009 (invalid day for Feb)